# In MySql what if i don't put closeCursor?

Tags: php, mysql

I created several queries like this one `$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM jeux_video');` and if i don't put the `closeCursor()` statement after each one, no error appears... So, in which cases `closeCursor()` is useful ?

Comment: Are you using php? If yes, please add it to your tags in your question. Is closeCursor a php-command? Please tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the manual:

> PDOStatement::closeCursor() frees up the connection to the server so
>   that other SQL statements may be issued, but leaves the statement in a
>   state that enables it to be executed again.
>
> This method is useful for database drivers that do not support
>   executing a PDOStatement object when a previously executed
>   PDOStatement object still has unfetched rows. If your database driver
>   suffers from this limitation, the problem may manifest itself in an
>   out-of-sequence error.

See, if that helps you in better understanding the use of close cursor.